# Skip multiple lines of code if there is no match

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, filter

[Pic of Consultants.xlsm headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BWqc.png)
[Pic of Customers.xlsx headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5GVP.png)

I have two excel files. One contains data identified as “customer information spreadsheet” and the second one (with the macro) is where a user could input data to match a consultant in the “consultants.xlsm”. The “customer information” spreadsheet contains customer/orders that need to match up to the consultant which will be open at the same time the macro is run. When the macro is run a name gets input to the “customer information” spreadsheet pulled from the consultant spreadsheet starting with the "a" column then going to the "b" column and so and so.

What I need help with is … if there is no match between customer information and consultant, then move to the next set of instructions. I have “`DIM rngConsultant`” up to 12 consultants but am only showing 3 below. I’m sure this is ugly code but its what I’ve gotten to work for the most part:

```
Sub FilterbyConsultant()

     Dim rngConsultant As Range
     With Workbooks("Consultants.xlsm").Sheets("Consultants")
     Set rngConsultant = .Range("A3", .Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp))
     End With
     Range("A1:A25000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=rngConsultant, Unique:=False

    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Workbooks("Consultants.xlsm").Sheets("Consultants").Range("A1")
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B12").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.Font.Bold = False
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Consultant"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Selection.AutoFilter

     Dim rngConsultant2 As Range
     With Workbooks("Consultants.xlsm").Sheets("Consultants")
     Set rngConsultant2 = .Range("B3", .Range("B" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp))
     End With
     Range("A1:A25000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=rngConsultant2, Unique:=False

    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Workbooks("Consultants.xlsm").Sheets("Consultants").Range("B1")
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B25").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Consultant"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Selection.AutoFilter


     Dim rngConsultant3 As Range
     With Workbooks("Consultants.xlsm").Sheets("Consultants")
     Set rngConsultant = .Range("C3", .Range("C" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp))
     End With
     Range("A1:A25000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=rngConsultant3, Unique:=False

    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Workbooks("Consultants.xlsm").Sheets("Consultants").Range("C1")
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B37").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Consultant"
    Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: I cannot deduce the layout of your worksheets from this code.  It appears worksheet "Consultants" has two header rows. Consultant1 is in column A, Consultant2 is in column B and so on.  Why are there multiple rows for a consultant?  Why B12 for Consultant1, B25 for Consultant2 and B37 for Consultant3.  Why `Range("A1:A25000").AdvancedFilter` for all three consultants.  What is in the active worksheet?  Please add detail to your question so the layout of your worksheets is clear.

Comment: Consultants.xlsm: Column A - A1 - "Consultant" A4 - Customer-12345; A5 - Customer 13456 .. Column B - B1 - "Consultant2" B4 - Customer-34345; B5 - Customer 55635

Comment: So you have 12 consultants, one per column A to L.  Row 1 contains the name of the consultant.  Rows 4 downwards contain the names of the customers for that consultant.  Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, was attaching images and editing the post so its easier to see. Added, but yes!

Comment: I entered Range("A1:A25000") because the spreadsheet changes and column A could be as little as 100 rows up to 20000

Comment: In worksheet "Consultants", row 1 contains the names of consultants and rows 4 downwards contain the names of the customers for the consultant.  In the active worksheet, column A contains the names of customers. For each row in the active worksheet, you want to name of the consultant for the customer written to column B.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I would loop down the active worksheet, extracting each customer name.  I would then search worksheet "Consultants" for that customer name.  If found, I would get the consultant name from row 1.  I would write the consultant name to column B of the row for the customer.  Is there any reason that would not work?

Comment: That's how it works now for the most part... consultants are pasted into column B of the active worksheet. I'm not sure how to write the loop to state if no match is found, then move to the next consultant.

Comment: I have written and tested the necessary code but need to document it.  It is gone midnight here so I will finish tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you created most of your code with the Macro Recorder.  The Macro Recorder does not know your objective so records each action as you perform it.  The result is syntactically correct but very poor VBA.  For example, `Select` is a slow command that any tutorial will tell you not to use.  The Macro Recorder does not have a choice.  You have added a `With` statement which the Macro Recorder cannot.

Having insulted your use of the Macro Recorder, I will admit to using it myself.  I do not use Import CSV file, Find and Sort often enough to remember the syntax or all the options.  I typically switch on the Macro Recorder, manually perform one of these complex commands, switch off the Macro Recorder and then adjust the recorded code to conform to recommended standards.

I created two workbooks that matched your descriptions: "Consultants.xlsm" and "CustomerInfo.xlsx".  For worksheet “Consultants”, I picked half-a-dozen names out of my local telephone directory and placed them along row 1.  Then starting at row 4, I placed from one to five company names under each consultant.  I created worksheet “Orders” in CustomerInfo.xlsx and copied a selection of company names to column A starting at row 4.

Note: I named the data worksheet.  It is bad idea to use the active worksheet.  This relies on the user have the correct worksheet active and makes the code confusing for a maintenance programmer.

Having created the workbooks and worksheets, I performed a search for one of the companies within worksheet “Consultants” and used the Macro Recorder to capture the syntax.  The result was:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Find(What:="Spitfire Insurance", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

I then tidied up that code for my macro.  Study the difference between the above code and the final code in my macro.  Try to deduce why I have made each change.  Come back with questions if necessary but the more you can work out for yourself, the faster you will develop your VBA skills.

My code below contains two macros: `AssignConsultantToOrder()` and `FindLastRowCol()`.

Excel VBA has several ways of finding the last row and column of a worksheet, but none work in every situation.  I used to decide which technique to use for each new macro.  I then decided to write a macro that would work in every situation of which I was aware and add it to my library.  I use PERSONAL.XLSB as a library.  I have modules named “LibExcel”, “LibOutlook” and “LibOffice”.  In these modules, I have placed macros designed for Excel, Outlook or any Microsoft Office package.  `FindLastRowCol()` is in “LibExcel”.  It uses every technique for find last row and column and then picks the best answers.  Don’t worry about this routine for the moment.  When you have some spare time, I believe you should study it.  You may also think it is worth creating PERSONAL.XLSB and copying this macro to it so it is available to any Excel macro you write.

I believe I have included enough comments in `AssignConsultantToOrder()` to allow you to understand it.  However, come back with questions if necessary.

```
Option Explicit

  ' I avoid using numeric literal for row and column numbers.
  ' If a column, for example, is moved, working through your code looking for
  ' every reference to that column is a nightmare. If you use constant, one
  ' change and your code is adjusted.

  Const RowConsultantsName As Long = 1
  Const RowConsultantsDataFirst As Long = 4

  Const ColOrdersCustomer As Long = 1
  Const ColOrdersConsultant As Long = 2
  Const RowOrdersDataFirst As Long = 4
Sub AssignConsultantToOrder()

  Dim ColOrdersLast As Long
  Dim ConsultantName As String
  Dim CustomerName As String
  Dim RngConsultant As Range
  Dim RowOrdersCrnt As Long
  Dim RowOrdersLast As Long
  Dim WbkConsultants As Workbook
  Dim WbkOrders As Workbook
  Dim WshtConsultants As Worksheet
  Dim WshtOrders As Worksheet

  ' I have created references to both workbooks.  It should not matter
  ' which workbook or worksheet is active when you start the macro
  Set WbkConsultants = Workbooks("Consultants.xlsm")
  Set WbkOrders = Workbooks("CustomerInfo.xlsx")

  Set WshtConsultants = WbkConsultants.Worksheets("Consultants")
  Set WshtOrders = WbkOrders.Worksheets("Orders")

  Call FindLastRowCol(WshtOrders, RowOrdersLast, ColOrdersLast)

  ' When I am developing a macro, I tend to write it in stages and use
  ' Debug.Print to prove that each stage is working before starting the
  ' next stage.
  'Debug.Print "Orders " & RowOrdersLast & " " & ColOrdersLast

  For RowOrdersCrnt = RowOrdersDataFirst To RowOrdersLast
    CustomerName = WshtOrders.Cells(RowOrdersCrnt, ColOrdersCustomer).Value
    'Debug.Print CustomerName
    With WshtConsultants
      Set RngConsultant = _
                .Cells.Find(What:=CustomerName, After:=.Cells(RowConsultantsDataFirst - 1, 1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
      If RngConsultant Is Nothing Then
        ' Customer not found so do not know consultant
        ConsultantName = ""
      Else
        ' Extract consultant name
        ConsultantName = .Cells(RowConsultantsName, RngConsultant.Column).Value
        'Debug.Print ConsultantName
      End If
    End With
    ' Copy consultant name to orders worksheet
    WshtOrders.Cells(RowOrdersCrnt, ColOrdersConsultant).Value = ConsultantName
  Next

End Sub
Public Sub FindLastRowCol(ByRef Wsht As Worksheet, ByRef RowLast As Long, _
                          ByRef ColLast As Long)

  ' Sets RowLast and ColLast to the last row and column with a value
  ' in worksheet Wsht

  ' The motivation for coding this routine was the discovery that Find by
  ' previous row found a cell formatted as Merge and Center but Find by
  ' previous column did not.
  ' I had known the Find would miss merged cells but this was new to me.

  '   Dec16  Coded
  ' 31Dec16  Corrected handling of UserRange
  ' 15Feb17  SpecialCells was giving a higher row number than Find for
  '          no reason I could determine.  Added code to check for a
  '          value on rows and columns above those returned by Find
  ' 25Jun17  Found column with value about that found by Find

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLastFind As Long
  Dim ColLastOther As Long
  Dim ColLastTemp As Long
  Dim ColLeft As Long
  Dim ColRight As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowIncludesMerged As Boolean
  Dim RowBot As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLastFind As Long
  Dim RowLastOther As Long
  Dim RowLastTemp As Long
  Dim RowTop As Long

  With Wsht

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastFind = 0
      ColLastFind = 0
    Else
      RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      ColLastFind = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Else
      If RowLastFind < Rng.Row Then
        RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      End If
      If ColLastFind < Rng.Column Then
        ColLastFind = Rng.Column
      End If
    End If

    Set Rng = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastOther = 0
      ColLastOther = 0
    Else
      RowLastOther = Rng.Row
      ColLastOther = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .UsedRange
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Else
      If RowLastOther < Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1 Then
        RowLastOther = Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1
      End If
      If ColLastOther < Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1 Then
        ColLastOther = Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
      End If
    End If

    If RowLastFind < RowLastOther Then
      ' Higher row found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While RowLastOther > RowLastFind
        ColLastTemp = .Cells(RowLastOther, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If ColLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(RowLastOther, 1).Value <> "" Then
          Debug.Assert False
          ' Is this possible
          ' Row after RowLastFind has value
          RowLastFind = RowLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        RowLastOther = RowLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf RowLastFind > RowLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible
    End If
    RowLast = RowLastFind

    If ColLastFind < ColLastOther Then
      ' Higher column found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While ColLastOther > ColLastFind
        RowLastTemp = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColLastOther).End(xlUp).Row
        If RowLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(1, ColLastOther).Value <> "" Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          ' Column after ColLastFind has value
          ' Possible causes:
          '   * Find does not recognise merged cells
          '   ' Find does not examine hidden cells
          ColLastFind = ColLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        ColLastOther = ColLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf ColLastFind > ColLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible
    End If
    ColLast = ColLastFind

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I set up the two workbooks to match, and running I get an error at ln46 : CustomerName = WshtOrders.Cells(RowOrdersCrnt, ColOrdersCustomer).Value

Comment: What is the error?   Does the error occur with the first data row in worksheet "Orders" or after some consultants have been identified.  If you hover the cursor over `RowOrdersCrnt` and `ColOrdersCustomer` you will see their values.  What are these values?  Please remove the quote from `'Debug.Print "Orders " & RowOrdersLast & " " & ColOrdersLast` and report the values output.

Comment: Says "Application-Defined" or Object-error .. I removed the quote and didn't see any further info. Named the sheet "Orders" on the CustomerInfo.xlsx and the sheet "Consultants" on the Consultants.xlsm correct?

Comment: I do not understand.  The macro has got past the statements creating references to the workbooks and the worksheets without error.  `Debug.Print "Orders " & RowOrdersLast & " " & ColOrdersLast` should have output something like "Orders 20 2" to the Immediate Window.  Does the error occur with the first data row in worksheet "Orders" or after some consultants have been identified?

Comment: It works :) haha... I had a space in the column "CustomerName" ... thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Everything is working perfectly... 1 more question... Is it possible to match the first 6 characters(only) in column A of Customer Name ... Example - 345Co: as opposed to an exact match?

Comment: @futureisnow  `CustomerName = Left$(WshtOrders.Cells(RowOrdersCrnt, ColOrdersCustomer).Value, 6)` 
will set `CustomerName` to the first 6 characters of the name.  In the `Find`, `What:=CustomerName & "*"` will find the first name which matches those first six characters.  Is that enough instructions?  I can amend the macro in my answer if necessary.

Comment: @futureisnow Thanks for the offer but I do not drink much.  I am retired; this is my hobby.